# Craft Queue not working when using AsyncQueue

Tags: queue

When using the [AsyncQueue](https://plugins.craftcms.com/async-queue) plugin, the queue never processes and just backs up on all the tasks it has to do, no matter what they are (search indexes, form notifications, sitemaps, …). We already added `runQueueAutomatically => true` to our general.php file, but this did not change anything. Did we miss any step to make this work?

The Queue runs perfectly fine when in a dev environment but stops working on live.

This issue is simliar to [#32503](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/32503/craft-queue-not-being-processed-listen-not-running), but this issue could not give us a working answer.

Comment: Anything in here help? https://github.com/ostark/craft-async-queue/issues/59